# URLRewriter.net fails relative paths when using more than one substring in URL

Tags: url, url-rewriting, asp.net-3.5

I have installed the URLRewriter on my server, and it works fine, but I have a rather big problem.

Relative links in hyperlinks, CSS-links, images etc. doesn't work when I have URLs with more than one substring.

E.g. (sorry, no http:// in front, as I do not have enough reputation):

website.com/Leje-og-udlejning-arbejdskraft leads to the path website.com/Workers.aspx and works just fine.

But

website.com/Leje-og-udlejning-arbejdskraft/Midtjylland leads to website.com/Workers.aspx?Region=Midtjylland using this line in the Web.config:

```
<rewrite url="~/Leje-og-udlejning-arbejdskraft/(.+)" to="~/Workers.aspx?Region=$1"/>
```

It rewrites just fine, but my relative links doesn't work anymore. CSS, Images, links and so on thinks my root is now http://website.com/Leje-og-udlejning-arbejdskraft, which of course doesn't exist.

Can't this be fixed?
All my links are correctly set using the ~/, like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" CssClass="black_text" NavigateUrl="~/Forgot-Password"
                        runat="server">I have forgotten my password</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, my solution was to add the following in my head-tag:

```
<base href="http://website.com/">
```

However, I hope you have some better suggestions, as I constantly move the project between localhost and online server, and have to correct it each time.